# getting access to jQuery.parseJSON(result) or transforming it into javascript array or smth

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        for(var k in result)
        {
            alert(k);
                    alert(result[k]);
        }
```

This code is working just fine.

But let's suppose I'm receiving object of the following type

```
status='FALSE'
message='error'
```

If you want to echo all this things first code is ok. It will alert everything.
But what If I want to work with this data, do some manipulations. In this case this for loop is a bit bad idea for me. So I have to transform probably this data into something new. Maybe constract some array during this loop and then read from array ? I think there must be some simple way to get access to that data. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If result is JSON data, you should be able to simply do:

```
result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
alert(result.status);
alert(result.message);
```

pareJSON turns the JSON data into a JavaScript Object. To access properties of an Object in JavaScript, you need to use dot notation.